# Shell Navigation in .net mauı

Tags: c#, maui

I am following a tutorial. Even though I tried to do it step by step, I could not add the routing feature to the application.

I want to go to the homepage with the button on the main page. This button calls the TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped event handler method.

https://github.com/tugbadokumaci/learn-MAUI/tree/master/PizzaMAUI/PizzaMAUI

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace PizzaMAUI.Pages; 

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//HomePage");
    }
}
```

AppShell.xaml

```
<ShellContent
    Title=""
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:MainPage}"
    Route="MainPage" />

<ShellContent
   Title="Home"
   ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:HomePage}"
   Route="HomePage" />
```

MauıProgram.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace PizzaMAUI;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>(); 
        AddPizzaServices(builder.Services);
        return builder.Build();
    }
    private static void AddPizzaServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<PizzaService>();

        services.AddSingleton<HomePage>();
        services.AddSingleton<HomeViewModel>();

        services.AddSingleton(provider => new HomeViewModel(provider.GetRequiredService<HomePage>()));
    }
}
```

HomePage.xaml.cs

```
namespace PizzaMAUI.Pages
{
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly HomeViewModel _homeViewModel;
        public HomePage(HomeViewModel homeViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _homeViewModel = homeViewModel;
            this.BindingContext = _homeViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel.cs

```
namespace PizzaMAUI.ViewModel
{
    public partial class HomeViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private readonly PizzaService _pizzaService;
        private HomePage homePage;

        public HomeViewModel(PizzaService pizzaService)
        {
            _pizzaService = pizzaService;
            Pizzas = new(_pizzaService.GetPopularPizzas());
        }

        public HomeViewModel(HomePage homePage)
        {
            this.homePage = homePage;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Pizza> Pizzas { get; set; }

    }
}
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
namespace PizzaMAUI;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(HomePage), typeof(HomePage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

Pizza.cs

```
using System;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace PizzaMAUI.Models
{
    public partial class Pizza : ObservableObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        [ObservableProperty, NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Amount))]
        private int _cartQuantity;

        public double Amount => CartQuantity * Price;
        public Pizza Clone() => MemberwiseClone() as Pizza;
    }
    
}
```

PizzaService.cs

```
using PizzaMAUI.Models;

namespace PizzaMAUI.Services
{
    public class PizzaService
    {
        private readonly static IEnumerable<Pizza> _pizzas = new List<Pizza>
        {
            new Pizza
            {
                Name = "Pizza 1",
                Image = "pizza1",
                Price = 1.45
            },
            new Pizza
            {
                Name = "Pizza 2",
                Image = "pizza2",
                Price = 2.45
            },
            new Pizza
            {
                Name = "Pizza 3",
                Image = "pizza3",
                Price = 4.34
            },
            new Pizza
            {
                Name = "Pizza 4",
                Image = "pizza4",
                Price = 3.5
            },
            new Pizza
            {
                Name = "Pizza 5",
                Image = "pizza5",
                Price = 7.45
            },
            new Pizza
            {
                Name = "Pizza 6",
                Image = "pizza6",
                Price = 1.5
            },
            new Pizza
            {
                Name = "Pizza 7",
                Image = "pizza7",
                Price = 6.5
            },
            new Pizza
            {
                Name = "Pizza 8",
                Image = "pizza8",
                Price = 7.77
            }
        };
        public IEnumerable<Pizza> GetAllPizzas() => _pizzas;
        public IEnumerable<Pizza> GetPopularPizzas(int count =6) => _pizzas.OrderBy(p=> Guid.NewGuid()).Take(count);
        public IEnumerable<Pizza> GetPizzas(string searchTerm) => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm) ? _pizzas : _pizzas.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    }
}
```

This was the source I followed: 1:03:15 https://youtu.be/bhr7pDfFzR4?si=q0KSzgqtX8taCtfT

First the application does not respond to the button, then it says "PizzaMAUI isn't responding"

Comment: You're passing in the `HomePage` into the `HomeViewModel` - that cannot work, you have a circular dependency. Only the `HomePage` should receive an instance of `HomeViewModel`, not the other way around. There should also only be one constructor. Shell won't know how to resolve the correct one like this. What errors do you see? Please include them.

Comment: Also, when applying the [MVVM pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm), the ViewModel must **never** know about (read: *have a dependency on*) the View (= Page).

Comment: what's the code of  `PizzaService ` and `Pizza` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set MauiProgram.cs, AppShell.xaml, AppShell.xaml.cs to default. and I changed the other files like this:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace PizzaMAUI.Pages; 
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
    }
    async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
    }
}
```

HomePage.xaml.cs

```
using PizzaMAUI.ViewModel;
namespace PizzaMAUI.Pages
{
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new HomeViewModel(new PizzaService());
        }
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel.cs

```
namespace PizzaMAUI.ViewModel
{
    public partial class HomeViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private readonly PizzaService _pizzaService;
        private HomePage homePage;
        public ObservableCollection<Pizza> Pizzas { get; set; }

        public HomeViewModel(PizzaService pizzaService)
        {
            _pizzaService = pizzaService;
            Pizzas = new(_pizzaService.GetPopularPizzas());
        }

        public HomeViewModel(HomePage homePage)
        {
            this.homePage = homePage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**